# localhost:3000/traceur SystemJS with AngularFire

Tags: systemjs, angularfire2

I picked the [getting started with Angular2 tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) format and only added in the angularfire2 part.

I installed firebase and angularfire2 using the steps on the [angularfire2 docs page](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md#3-install-angularfire-2-and-firebase)

Below is my systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
      'angularfire2':               'npm:angularfire2'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      angularfire2: {
        main: 'index.js',
        defautExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Then I am simply importing it like so:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
```

Then I keep getting this error:

[image]

Any hint what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config maps angularfire2 to `node_modules/angularfire2/index.js`, which is written is es6, so SystemJS tries to compile it using traceur, and can not find it.

The easy fix would be to configure it so it loads the bundle in `angular2/bundles/angularFire2.umd.js`, not `index.js`.

So `angularfire2` in `packages`

```
  angularfire2: {
    main: 'index.js'
```

needs to be changed to

```
  angularfire2: {
    main: 'bundles/angularFire2.umd.js'
```

Also, angularFire depends on Firebase, so, as @Jonathon Oates said in his answer, you need to provide configuration for Firebase too.

Comment: I did @jonathan-oates suggestion too. You might wanna update your answer to include that bit. Thanks. Fixed for me.

Comment: Yep, added a reference to his answer

Comment: @Rexford and @artem I can't find any similar question other than this so I thought I might ask you as well guys. 

How did you manage to import the `angularfire2/database` and `angularfire2/auth` ? 

I was trying to import them from `map:{}` as `'angularfire2/database': 'npm:angularfire2/database'` and `'angularfire2/auth': 'npm:angularfire2/auth'`. 

Please see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125733/angular-typescript-error-traceur-404-not-found) 

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @artem — I was having the exact same problem!

You may also need to reference Firebase in your `map` too e.g.

```
'firebase': 'npm:firebase'
```

And add Firebase to your `packages` e.g.

```
  'angularfire2': {
    main: './bundles/angularFire2.umd.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'firebase': {
    main: './firebase.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
```

Otherwise you may see a new 404 error for Firebase.